# How to indent multiple lines of code in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have tried using "reindent lines" after highlighting the lines but that doesn't work (in fact it removes indentation). For example I want a quick way to

take a script like this

```
#parameters
b=2
c=1
d=4
q=3
```

and turn it into this

```
#parameters
    b=2
    c=1
    d=4
    q=3
```

in Rstudio

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Highlighting the code of interest and hitting tab should add another level of indentation. Shift-tab will remove a level of indentation.

Comment: wow, how incredibly simple. I just assumed that would delete all your code and replace it with a single indentation.

Comment: @MHH Other similar things RStudio does that may differ from what you might expect is that you can highlight a section and type a `"` or `{` or others and it'll enclose your highlighted section with the desired character instead of replacing it like a text editor would.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Shift-tab. Life changing!

Comment: SOOO helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could use a shortcut. First, highlight the lines you want to indent, and then press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> (at least, that is the combination on my keyboard).

If you want to move in the other direction, then press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

RStudio will let you use Regex in Find and Replace. You can search for `\n` and replace with `\n\t`, which will do what (I think) you want.

The automatic indent is designed to format your code so that there is indenting where appropriate (inside a pair of brackets, for example). 'Reindent' is for when there has been automatic indenting applied which is no longer appropriate (eg brackets have been removed).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. `\n` finds no results for me (and it should, because I do have more than one line in my file), and searches of the internet for multiline search in Rstudio have so far not found any hint that this is possible. I am using Rstudio 1.1.456

Answer (score 0):

re format code and reindent works for me. But, for your example, I think it is more based on the space a tab creates. Also, the below link is a good way to write good codes

https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml

http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/r.html

Comment: the link to the style guide doesn't work any more. it's now: https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml